# Show that a language with union is not regular by using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

Given the language $L:= { \{ c^{2k} w \ \vert \ k \ge 1, \ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \ and \  \vert w\vert_a \ = \ \vert w\vert_b \} \  \cup \ \{ a,b \}^* }$

I'm really unsure how to even start because of the union.

I tried it with $w=a^nb^n$ but my correction said that it's
pumpable because it is in $\{ a,b \}^*$ which makes sense.

What would be a good word to start with?
I guess there are several cases i need to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ was regular, so would be $L \cap c^+\Sigma^* = \{c^{2k}w\mid k\geq 1, w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \text{ and }|w|_a = |w|_b\}$.

That means that if you prove that this language is not regular, then $L$ cannot be regular too (that way, we got rid of the union).

Now you can take it from here with pumping lemma, starting from $c^2a^nb^n$!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to make a little "sketch". So i take the word `c^2a^nb^n` as you said. Because `|xy| <= n and |y| >= 1`, y has to be `y = a^k and 1<=k<=n`. With that i can pump xyz to xyyz and get `c^2a^(n+k)b^n` which is it not regular because the amount of as and bs is not the same. Would this make sense or did i miss something (I feel like i did).

Comment: Technically, $y$ could contain $c$'s, but overall you have the idea.

Comment: So i would have to make several cases?

Comment: Yes, and find a contradiction in each case.

Comment: Thank you very much!